# How to use groupby with combination of an array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am studying some pandas from the "Python-for-Data-Analysis" book, and I have stumbled upon a piece of code I can't understand:

```
by_tz_os = cframe.groupby(['tz', op_system])
```

Where `cframe` is a dataframe with multiple columns, and `op_system` is an array generated from:

```
op_system = np.where(cframe['a'].str.contains('Windows'), 'Windows', 'Not Windows')
```

meaning, corresponding to the length of the given `cframe` dataframe.

How does this groupby work, with another array, is it just adding the array as a column and then grouping by the `tz` and the `op_system` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here a 2-level grouping:

- The first level of grouping is *tz*.
- The second level is a "division" of each of above groups into 2 parts,

  - *Windows* - *a* column contains *Windows*
  - *Not Windows* - "other" rows.

You can think of *op_system* as something like "additional column" in
*cframe* (actually it is a *Numpy* (1-D) array, but acts as a column).